# How to convert an array of dictionaries to a json string in swift without optional value

Tags: ios, arrays, json, xcode, swift4

I want convert array of dictionaries to a json string so i have used

```
func json(from object: NSMutableArray) -> String? {
    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object) else {
        return nil
    }

    return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}
```

and it is returning a json string but with an optional before the stirng

```
finalString = json(from: saveArray)
print(finalString)
```

> Optional("[{\"CreatedOn\":\"Thursday, Mar 29, 2018\",\"DayName\":\"Wed\",\"EmployeeID\":\"1\",\"AppointmentType\":\"3\",\"FromTime\":\"09:00:00\",\"AppointmentDate\":\"Wednesday, May 16, 2018\",\"ToTime\":\"10:00:00\",\"CreatedBy\":\"40289\",\"PatientID\":\"17586\",\"ResourceID\":\"1\",\"PatientConditionId\":\"17590\"},{\"CreatedOn\":\"Thursday, Mar 29, 2018\",\"DayName\":\"Thu\",\"EmployeeID\":\"1\",\"AppointmentType\":\"3\",\"FromTime\":\"09:00:00\",\"AppointmentDate\":\"Thursday, May 17, 2018\",\"ToTime\":\"10:00:00\",\"CreatedBy\":\"40289\",\"PatientID\":\"17586\",\"ResourceID\":\"1\",\"PatientConditionId\":\"17590\"},{\"CreatedOn\":\"Thursday, Mar 29, 2018\",\"DayName\":\"Fri\",\"EmployeeID\":\"1\",\"AppointmentType\":\"3\",\"FromTime\":\"09:00:00\",\"AppointmentDate\":\"Friday, May 18, 2018\",\"ToTime\":\"10:00:00\",\"CreatedBy\":\"40289\",\"PatientID\":\"17586\",\"ResourceID\":\"1\",\"PatientConditionId\":\"17590\"}]")

and when i unwrap this value...

```
finalString = json(from: saveArray)
print(finalString!)
```

then I get...

```
[
{
"CreatedOn": "Thursday, Mar 29, 2018",
"DayName": "Wed",
"EmployeeID": "1",
"AppointmentType": "3",
"FromTime": "09:00:00",
"AppointmentDate": "Wednesday, May 16, 2018",
"ToTime": "10:00:00",
"CreatedBy": "40289",
"PatientID": "17586",
"ResourceID": "1",
"PatientConditionId": "17590"
},
{
"CreatedOn": "Thursday, Mar 29, 2018",
"DayName": "Thu",
"EmployeeID": "1",
"AppointmentType": "3",
"FromTime": "09:00:00",
"AppointmentDate": "Thursday, May 17, 2018",
"ToTime": "10:00:00",
"CreatedBy": "40289",
"PatientID": "17586",
"ResourceID": "1",
"PatientConditionId": "17590"
},
{
"CreatedOn": "Thursday, Mar 29, 2018",
"DayName": "Fri",
"EmployeeID": "1",
"AppointmentType": "3",
"FromTime": "09:00:00",
"AppointmentDate": "Friday, May 18, 2018",
"ToTime": "10:00:00",
"CreatedBy": "40289",
"PatientID": "17586",
"ResourceID": "1",
"PatientConditionId": "17590"
}
]
```

just an array structure.

now how can i achieve the json string structure without the optional value?????

Comment: put ! at the end of String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

Comment: no it returns the array structure... but i want this string structure.... "[{\"CreatedOn\":\"Thursday, Mar 29, 2018\",\"DayName\":\"Wed\",\"EmployeeID\":\"1\",\"AppointmentType\":\"3\",\"FromTime\":\"09:00:00\",\"AppointmentDate\":\"Wednesday, May 16, 2018\",\"ToTime\":\"10:00:00\",\"CreatedBy\":\"40289\",\"PatientID\":\"17586\",\"ResourceID\":\"1\",\"PatientConditionId\":\"17590\"}]"

Comment: Your problem here seems to be misunderstanding what Optional values are in Swift. I would suggest reading the free Swift book from Apple (there are many other resources) about what Optionals are and how to use them. This will allow you to answer your question :D

Comment: with all respect i know what is optional value in swift. My question is that when i unwrap the string why the structure changes?

Comment: do you want to say 
"[{"CreatedOn":"Thursday, Mar 29, 2018","DayName":"Wed","EmployeeID":"1","AppointmentType":"3","FromTime":"09:00:00","AppointmentDate":"Wednesday, May 16, 2018","ToTime":"10:00:00","CreatedBy":"40289","PatientID":"17586","ResourceID":"1","PatientConditionId":"17590"}]"
this is json string structure in swift?

Comment: @Somenath your function returns `String?` if you don't want it to be optional... why are you returning an optional string?

Comment: How can i achive this structure ?

"[{\"CreatedOn\":\"Thursday, Mar 29, 2018\",\"DayName\":\"Wed\",\"EmployeeID\":\"1\",\"AppointmentType\":\"3\",\"FromTime\":\"09:00:00\",\"AppointmentDate\":\"Wednesday, May 16, 2018\",\"ToTime\":\"10:00:00\",\"CreatedBy\":\"40289\",\"PatientID\":\"17586\",\"ResourceID\":\"1\",\"PatientConditionId\":\"17590\"}]"

Comment: My concern is not with the optional... i just want to know why the structure get changed if i unwrap it?

Comment: OK, just looking at this now. Why are you using an `NSMutableArray`? i.e. why `Mutable`? And why `NSArray`? If you're using Swift you should be using `Array`.

Comment: Also... what are you actually trying to achieve here? Are you going to be uploading this JSON to an endpoint (or something similar)?

Comment: Yes we are working with .net apis and the backend guys said that they want the structure with backslashes. otherwise they cannot parse it.

Comment: You shouldn't be sending JSON as a string though. You just send the data. The data is then unwrapped on the other end into objects etc... JSON is NOT a String. JSON is a data format to represent "Javascript objects"

Comment: then what value should i send to the api?

Optional("[{\"CreatedOn\":\"Thursday, Mar 29, 2018\",\"DayName\":\"Wed\",\"EmployeeID\":\"1\",\"AppointmentType\":\"3\",\"FromTime\":\"09:00:00\",\"AppointmentDate\":\"Wednesday, May 16, 2018\",\"ToTime\":\"10:00:00\",\"CreatedBy\":\"40289\",\"PatientID\":\"17586\",\"ResourceID\":\"1\",\"PatientConditionId\":\"17590\"}])"...... this one?

Comment: No... that's a string. And the `Optional(...)` bit only comes from the debug description of the string (i.e. when you use `print(optionalThing)`). What you should send through the api is the `data` from your function. Don't turn the `data` into a String. Just add the `data` as the request body for your URL request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by conditional binding

```
if let finalString = json(from: saveArray) {
  print(finalString) //here final string is unwrapped
} else {
  print("Invalid JSON")
}
```

or

```
guard let finalString = json(from: saveArray) else {
   print("finalString is nil")
   return
}

print(finalString)
```

Comment: no, I want the only string value which is inside the optional like "[{\"CreatedOn\":\"Thursday, Mar 29, 2018\",\"DayName\":\"Wed\",\"EmployeeID\":\"1\",\"AppointmentType\":\"3\",\"FromTime\":\"09:00:00\",\"AppointmentDate\":\"Wednesday, May 16, 2018\",\"ToTime\":\"10:00:00\",\"CreatedBy\":\"40289\",\"PatientID\":\"17586\",\"ResourceID\":\"1\",\"PatientConditionId\":\"17590\"}]"

Comment: Use this code and just check the console you will get only string value without "optional" .

Comment: i got the string value but it is without the backslashes.

Comment: It is printed on console thats why it has "\" otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the return value as optional

```
... -> String?
```

so it's always optional even if the result is not.

Unwrap or optional bind the optional

```
finalString! 

if let final = finalString { ...
```

to get rid of `Optional` in the print-out.

---

A better solution is to mark the function as `can throw` and hand over the error of `JSONSerialization`. It's a much more consistent error handling than returning an optional. If there is no error the string created from the `Data` object can never be `nil`.

**And don't use  `NSMutableArray` in Swift.**

```
func json(from object: [[String:Any]]) throws -> String {
    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object)
    return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
}
```

and use it

```
do {
   let finalString = json(from: ...
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: I did this earlier and now i double checked it but it returns the same value with optional keyword

Comment: Of course you have to put the `json(from` call in a `do - catch` block. Don't ignore errors with `try?`

Comment: actually why the escape characters are removed from the optional string?

Comment: The backslashes are virtual not real. They are only needed to be able to display the entire string as literal string.

Comment: we are working with .net apis and the backend guys said that they want the structure with backslashes. otherwise they cannot parse it. Now what can i do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the .net stuff but backslashes to escape double quotes are only used in JSON if a value is a literal string containing double quotes.